# Start new console application in new thread

Tags: c#, powershell, teamcity

I am trying to start a .exe program from the build runner, but I don't want it to run in the teamcity console, I want a brand new console that runs independently from the current build. So far I have tried a few things without any success.

Tried with a powershell script:

```
$ErrorMessage = "POWERSHELL ERROR"
try {
  Write-Output "About to start backend"
  Start-Process Program.exe
  Write-Output "Started backend"
} Catch {
  Write-Output $ErrorMessage
  exit(1)
}
```

Tried starting a new console with this command:

```
Start Program.exe
```

I'm starting to wonder if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the teamcity forum, thought I might share it here though. My problem was caused to an issue with the build agent caused by windows.
Check out the full explanation [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Known+Issues#KnownIssues-AgentrunningasWindowsServiceLimitations).

To solve the problem, you need to run the agent by running the command "agent.bat run" in the agent's bin folder under your installation directory.

Answer (score 2):

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList @("-NoExit", "-Command Start-Process cmd")
```

Comment: Did not work, just tried this :/ Does this work for you?

Comment: For me that spawns a new powershell shell and that spawns a new cmd shell.

Comment: Of course this works for me as well when I run it directly from the powershell, but it doesn't when I run it trough teamcity.